# sql left join between 3 table and null values

Tags: sql, database, go

I have these following tables:

- user

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Olivia | Liam |
| 2 | Oliver | Noah |

- homework_log

| id | status | supervisor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 1 |
| 2 | supervisor approve | 2 |
| 3 | supervisor approve | null |

- homework_submission

| id | status | supervisor_id | homework_log_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | approved | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | supervisor approve | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | supervisor approve | 2 | 3 |

this is sql query:

```
SELECT
    hl.id as id
     , hl.status
     , concat(au.first_name, ' ', au.last_name) as supervisor_name
FROM homework_log AS hl
         left join homework_submission as hs on hs.homework_log_id = hl.id
         left join user as u on u.id = hs.supervisor_id
```

this query will only include supervisor_name when status is complete . I understand that is happen because of left join (we join with homework_submission) . what i want is to also include supervisor name when supervisor_id in homework_log has value.

so i update query to this :

```
SELECT
     hl.id as id
     , hl.status
     , concat(au.first_name, ' ', au.last_name) as supervisor_name
     , concat(au2.first_name, ' ', au2.last_name) AS supervisor_name2
FROM audit_logs AS al
          left join homework_submission as hs on hs.homework_log_id = hl.id
         left join user as u on u.id = hl.supervisor_id
         left join user as u2 on u2.id = al.supervisor_id
```

note : I put both supervisor_name2 and supervisor_name here just to show you all of my tries.
when status is "completed" :

- the supervisor_name2 have a correct vale (print supervisor name for all rows )
- the supervisor_name have a incorrect vale (did not print supervisor name when al.supervisor_id is null)

when status is "supervisor approve":

- the supervisor_name have a correct value but supervisor_name did not has value at all.

I also find this great solution :

```
SELECT
     hl.id as id
     , hl.status
     , COALESCE(concat(au.first_name, ' ', au.last_name), concat(au2.first_name, ' ',              au2.last_name)) AS supervisor_name
FROM audit_logs AS al
          left join homework_submission as hs on hs.homework_log_id = hl.id
         left join user as u on u.id = hl.supervisor_id
         left join user as u2 on u2.id = al.supervisor_id
```

the result is correct except when supervisor_id in homework_log is null :(

my question is how can I edit this query to include supervisor name when one or both of  supervisor_id in table homework_log and homework_submission have a value.

Comment: Would you please update your database tag (which database are you using)? Also why would you think that first SQL would only return supervisor name when its status is 'completed'? Though you have typo in that code, if you correct them you would get all 3 not just the status completed. Or do you mean that was what you want? Please show us the desired output, rather than your trials. Also, what does this has to do with Go? Do you mean something like how to run this query with sqlx, gorm , etc or what?

Comment: I din't read futher than the first SQL before. Reading on, you don't even have an audit_logs table and still unclear what you are trying to achieve. In general, your table design is bad. ie: Why would homework_log have a dependency on supervisor_id? It also  exists in homework_submission. Do you want to create 2 different relations? Looks like you have redundant data but not sure, we don't know your intentions. (this is known as XY problem)

Comment: thanks Cetin for your comment . first of all , this problem face me in my work so i just try to emulate it ( don't put all table columns that's why you see table design is bad .) and for your question why i think is only return supervisor name when its status is 'completed' because of the lift join is on homework_submission ,also i try it on my actual DB . and i write the desire output in the question " how can I edit this query to include supervisor name when one or both of supervisor_id in table homework_log and homework_submission have a value." .

Comment: i write this query for GO project that way I tag it maybe Go developer help me. I'm sorry i write  audit_logs by mistake I mean homework_log :)

Comment: Your first query wouldn't return nulls. It would return all those 3 logs with supervisor names (because you are linking supervisor over homework_submission and you don't have any null values there, you have only supervisor 1 and 2).  You can check this fiddle where I only corrected typos on your first query: https://dbfiddle.uk/HXzmpOUr
  In other words you don't need any coalesce() work here. Using concat or || or + is dependent on the backend you are using. All or some of them might work. I don't know your backend but the code would be valid for postgreSQL or mySQL at least.

Comment: Question is not directly related to Go and would be the same. If you are using an ORM like Gorm, then you could directly access that information via dot notation. something like hl.Homework_Submission.Supervisor.FirstName (might create a method for fullname on user struct). You didn't really tell us your intention yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.5.1.1.1

> Concatenates the text representations of all the arguments. **NULL arguments are ignored.**

As you can see in the documentation, `concat` ignores `NULL` arguments but keeps and concatenates non-`NULL` arguments. So `COALESCE` doesn't work as you expect because in each `concat` call you have at least 1 non-NULL argument (i.e., `' '` the white space character), therefore each `concat` call will be either return the full name of `' '`.

You can use `||` instead of `concat` if you want the operation to return `NULL` if any of its operands are `NULL`. For example:

```sql
COALESCE(
    (u1.first_name || ' ' || u1.last_name),
    (u2.first_name || ' ' || u2.last_name)
)
```

Comment: @Abeer, but there is no nulls returning in the first query. I don't think it explains why first query only returns the row with 'completed' (it returns all 3 of them in fact).